# Spaces between separator and value in csv file

Tags: csv

Would like to confirm something related to csv format. I am loading files into database and use enclosed by as double quotes because it could happen in my csv that some fields contain values between double quotes - that's normal. However sometimes I get files where there is situation that between separator and double quote as enclosed by are e.g spaces which makes a problem for my code which is treating that as value e.g:

```
1,   "value1",something
```

In this case value from second position will be inserted to database as :

```
spacespace"value1"
```

My client who is providing the csv claims that it is normal and my code should place just `value1` as value into database. However from my understanding it's not correct as in this case spaces belongs to value so enclosed by is not working as it should. Am I right with this and what document can I refer to in this particural case to explain the customer that what he is saying is not true and that he should avoid spaces in this case otherwise it will belong to value. Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Specification

Comment: @melpomene first of all am i right what i wrote? Can't find anything about in this link - what sentence you ment?

Comment: "with the records divided into fields separated by delimiters (typically a single reserved character such as comma, semicolon, or tab; *sometimes the delimiter may include optional spaces*)" ... "without additional information (such as whether RFC 4180 is honored), *a file claimed simply to be in "CSV" format is not fully specified*" ... "In some CSV implementations, leading and trailing spaces and tabs are trimmed (ignored). Such trimming is forbidden by RFC 4180, which states "Spaces are considered part of a field and should not be ignored.""

Comment: @melpomene mean what i wrote is correct according to: "Spaces are considered part of a field and should not be ignored." However when i show it to customer he can say - you know but there is word "should" so not obligated...

Answer (score 3):

There is not really a standard for csv. There is however [RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) that lists some rules/information.

As for the example csv:

```
1,   "value1",something
```

This could actually be seen as invalid csv data, because in practice some csv parsers will throw an error if there are spaces between a separator and the first double quote.

If that row gets parsed however, the spaces before the `"` should be removed/skipped.

But for the following row, the general rule is to preserve the spaces because they are inside the quotes:

```
1,"   value1",something
```

Of course the best option is to (let your client) generate correct csv data to begin with.

Comment: i agree if its within quotes but if not whole value is traded as value even including quotes as value part and not enclosed part.

Comment: @DinoDinn Yes, different parsers will treat this in different ways. That's why it should not be accepted as valid csv. I would push the client to provide valid csv, it's a lot easier to generate correct csv than to fix it while reading (and could cause extra problems later on - updates of software/parser etc..).

Comment: @DinoDinn And in case you have to fix this yourself: you can trim the left spaces, but only remove the two outer double quotes (do not trim all double quotes) and replace 2 double quotes with one -- because you could have "monitor 17""" for example.

Comment: you said: "That's why it should not be accepted as valid csv" but wht document can i refer to confirm that?

Comment: @DinoDinn 1) There's not really a document/standard about that, but the fact that the parser of your database preservers the spaces might be the best proof/argument. 2) some links: [Implementation note: In Excel, leading spaces between the comma..](http://creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm) - [That cell is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863852/space-before-quote-in-csv-field) - https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/204

Comment: From [RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) - "Each field may or may not be enclosed in double quotes ....  If fields are not enclosed with double quotes, then double quotes may not appear inside the fields.". The first example in your answer, `1,<spaces>"value1",something` shows a field `<spaces>"value1"` that is not **enclosed** in double quotes but double quotes appear inside the field and so is not valid CSV. The second example in your answer, `1,"<spaces>value1",something`, and  `1,<spaces>value1,something` would both be valid CSV.