# Unix commands to fill gaps between dates in a file

Tags: unix, awk

I want to find the records with same name and age but different date. Then if there is a gap between the prev date and next line date , i have to fill the gap.

Sample data
file.txt

```
20230907,Allan,29,Marketing
20230912,Allan,29,VirtualAssistant
20230913,Allan,29,Programmer
20230920,Daniel,28,Engineer
20230922,Daniel,28, Photographer
```

What I did so far:

```
#create zero byte file for all filled gaps
cat /dev/null > fillGap.txt
For line in `awk -F"," '{print $2","$3}' file.txt`;do
#if name,age NOT found in fillGap.txt then grep everything that matches in file.txt
if [[ -z `grep -w ${line} fillGap.txt` ]];then
grep -w ${line} file.txt > MatchNameAge.txt
#this is the part of checking if there is a gap between dates and if so, gaps will be filled. I haven't figured it out on how I should do it. maybe you could help me
#after filling the gap, the transformed will be appended in fileGap.txt
else
  #if name,age have already found in filledGap.txt, there's nothing to do.
fi
done
```

#my code lacks a lot of context cause I only have the idea and keep on trying piece by piece on how I code it.

This idea might works fine but, using for loop for large files would cause long running.

Can you help me achieve goal below with shorter runtime as possible?

Desired Output:

```
20230907,Allan,29,Marketing
20230908,Allan,29,Marketing
20230909,Allan,29,Marketing
20230910,Allan,29,Marketing
20230911,Allan,29,Marketing
20230912,Allan,29,VirtualAssistant
20230913,Allan,29,Programmer
20230920,Daniel,28,Engineer
20230921,Daniel,28,Engineer
20230922,Daniel,28, Photographer
```

I'd like yo add such cases in my data like below. What if I have a date that is end of the month and the next date is the next month

```
20230930,Allan,29,Programmer
20231004,Allan,29,Engineer
```

Output should look like this

```
20230930,Allan,29,Programmer
20231001,Allan,29,Programmer
20231002,Allan,29,Programmer
20231003,Allan,29,Programmer
20231004,Allan,29,Engineer
```

What matters is that filling gap between dates with same "name,age"

Comment: is the input file guaranteed to already be sorted by date + name + age?

Comment: @markp-fuso no. The file is not guaranteed to be already sorted

Comment: You should have included some interesting cases in your sample input/output such as same name but different age and, more importantly, dates that cross month and year boundaries, especially across Feb 29 in a leap year. What you currently have would only test the most basic sunny-day cases so a script that produces the expected output you provided from the sample input you provided could be completely wrong for other dates.

Answer (score 5):

Using any `sort` plus GNU awk for time functions and `gensub()`:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sort -t, -k2,2 -k1,1n "${@:--}" |
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    ($2 == p[2]) && ($3 == p[3]) {
        for ( date=nextDate(p[1]); date<$1; date=nextDate(date) ) {
            sub(/[^,]+/,date,p[0])
            print p[0]
        }
    }
    {
        print
        split($0,p)
        p[0] = $0
    }

    function nextDate(date,secs) {
        date = gensub(/(.{4})(..)(..)/,"\\1 \\2 \\3",1,date)
        secs = mktime(date " 12 0 0") + (24 * 60 * 60)
        return strftime("%Y%m%d",secs)
    }
'
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file.txt
20230907,Allan,29,Marketing
20230908,Allan,29,Marketing
20230909,Allan,29,Marketing
20230910,Allan,29,Marketing
20230911,Allan,29,Marketing
20230912,Allan,29,VirtualAssistant
20230913,Allan,29,Programmer
20230920,Daniel,28,Engineer
20230921,Daniel,28,Engineer
20230922,Daniel,28, Photographer
```

Alternatively, using any awk just replace the `nextDate()` function above with this version:

```
    function nextDate(date,     i,tmp,year,month,day,maxDays) {
        year  = substr(date,1,4)+0
        month = substr(date,5,2)+0
        day   = substr(date,7,2)+0

        # see https://www.timeanddate.com/date/leapyear.html
        if ( (month == 2) && !(year % 4) && ((year % 100) || !(year % 400)) ) {
            maxDays = 29
        }
        else {
            if ( !(1 in daysIn) ) {
                split("1 31 2 28 3 31 4 30 5 31 6 30 7 31 8 31 9 30 10 31 11 30 12 31",tmp," ")
                for ( i=1; i in tmp; i+=2 ) {
                    daysIn[i] = tmp[i+1]
                }
            }
            maxDays = daysIn[month]
        }

        if ( ++day > maxDays ) {
            day = 1
            if ( ++month > 12 ) {
                month = 1
                year++
            }
        }

        return sprintf("%04d%02d%02d",year,month,day)
    }
```

Comment: Clever! I would have mindlessly implemented the POSIX versions of `mktime` and `strftime` when in fact you don't even need to convert the date at all. +1

Comment: @Fravadona If you implemented those anyway and put them under a BSD2 license, I could include them in [`cppawk`](https://www.kylheku.com/cgit/cppawk/about), where they would be available via some new header file (which would suppress the definitions on GNU Awk).

Comment: @Kaz my implementation of `mktime` doesn't handle the timezones, and `strftime` doesn't return a formatted string but fills an array with the components of the date instead. Supporting the timezones and the format string would need a lot of code

Answer (score 3):

Dates are a bit tricky to deal with in `awk`, so I tend to write dedicated functions to deal with them.

Here is an example solution that assumes a sorted input (tested with  `gawk` and `mawk`):

*parse.awk*

```awk
BEGIN { 
  sid = 60 * 60 * 24;   # Seconds in a day
  FS = OFS = ",";
}

# Convert date to seconds-since-the-unix-epoch (Jan 1, 1970)
function getdate(d) {
  year  = substr(d, 1, 4);
  month = substr(d, 5, 2);
  day   = substr(d, 7, 2);

  return mktime(year" "month" "day" 00 00 00");
}

# Add one day to date
function addday(d) {
  return strftime("%Y%m%d", getdate(d) + sid);
}

($2 SUBSEP $3) in nameage {
  d = nameage[$2,$3];

  while (addday(d) < $1) {
    print (addday(d), $2, $3, occupation[$2,$3]);
    d = addday(d);
  }
}

{
  nameage[$2,$3]    = $1;
  occupation[$2,$3] = $4;
}

1;
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f parse.awk infile
```

Output:

```
20230907,Allan,29,Marketing
20230908,Allan,29,Marketing
20230909,Allan,29,Marketing
20230910,Allan,29,Marketing
20230911,Allan,29,Marketing
20230912,Allan,29,VirtualAssistant
20230913,Allan,29,Programmer
20230920,Daniel,28,Engineer
20230921,Daniel,28,Engineer
20230922,Daniel,28, Photographer
```

Comment: `mktime` and `strftime` are GNU specific, but OP's "UNIX" might have it. It's still possible to implement the same functionalities with a POSIX `awk` tho

Comment: @Fravadona: This works at least with `gawk`, `mawk` and `nawk`

Comment: @Fravadona: I take it back, this does not work in `nawk` because of the lacking time functions. Adding a note

Answer (score 1):

Solution in [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr):

```
$ txr filldate.txr data
20230907,Allan,29,Marketing
20230908,Allan,29,Marketing
20230909,Allan,29,Marketing
20230910,Allan,29,Marketing
20230911,Allan,29,Marketing
20230912,Allan,29,VirtualAssistant
20230913,Allan,29,Programmer
20230920,Daniel,28,Engineer
20230921,Daniel,28,Engineer
20230922,Daniel,28, Photographer
```

Code in `filldate.txr`:

```
@(repeat)
@  (cases)
@date0,@name,@age,@rest0
@    (trailer)
@date1,@name,@age,@rest1
@    (bind dates @[giterate (op nequal date1)
                            (opip
                              (time-parse "%Y%m%d")
                              .(time-utc)
                              (+ 86400)
                              (time-str-utc "%Y%m%d"))
                            date0])
@    (output)
@      (repeat)
@dates,@name,@age,@rest0
@      (end)
@    (end)
@  (or)
@line
@    (do (put-line line))
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Colorized with Vim:

[image: Colorized with Vim]

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and date):

```
sed -E '/\n/!N
       /(,[^,]*,[^,]*,).*\n.*\1/{/^([^,]*,).*\n\1/D
       s/^([^,]*)(,.*\n)/echo "&$(date -d "\1 +1 day" +%Y%m%d)\2"/e}
       P;D' file
```

Use the `N;P;D` sed idiom which appends the next line to the current line, prints/deletes the first line and repeats.

In this case, append the next line if one or no other lines in the pattern space.

Compare the second and third fields of those lines and if the same:

Compare the dates of those lines and if the same then delete the first line and repeat.

If the dates are not the same, insert a line with tomorrows date between the first and second lines.

Regardless, print/delete the first line and repeat.

N.B. The brunt of the work is done by the evaluated substitution which needs to interpolate an echo command.

---

If the file is not sorted use:

```
sort -t, -k2,3 -k1,1 file |
sed -E '/\n/!N
       /(,[^,]*,[^,]*,).*\n.*\1/{/^([^,]*,).*\n\1/D
       s/^([^,]*)(,.*\n)/echo "&$(date -d "\1 +1 day" +%Y%m%d)\2"/e}
       P;D'
```

Answer (score -1):

Using [sqlite3](/questions/tagged/sqlite3):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# create header in file.txtA
a=$(head -1 file.txt | sed -e 's/[^,]*,*/#/g')
b=abcdefgh;
c=$(echo ${b:0:${#a}} | sed -E 's/(.)/\1,/g')
c=${c%?}
sed -i -e "1i$c" file.txt

# create output
sql=".import file.txt file
   update file set a=date(substr(a,1,4)||'-'||substr(a,5,2)||'-'||substr(a,7,2));
   with cte as (
      select a,b,c,d,lead(a) over (partition by b order by a) as m from file
      union all
      select date(a,'1 day'),b,c,d,m
      from cte
      where date(a,'1 day') < m
   )
   select replace(a,'-','') as a,b,c,d
   from cte
   order by a,b;
"
db=$(mktemp)
echo "$sql" | sqlite3 -csv $db

# strip header and remove db
sed -i -e '1d' file.txt
rm -f $db
```

- A temporary file is created for the database (using: `mktemp`)
- Headers are inserted into `file.txt`. This is done using the most simple name I could think of, so the first column will be named `a`, the second `b`, ... (see NOTE)
- In the SQL part the dates are formatted so `20230907` becomes `2023-09-07`. This is so SQLite can calculate tomorrow using `date('2023-09-07','1 day')`.
- When querying the `-` signs in the date are removed again.
- The `cte` add records based on the value of `lead(a) over (partition by b order by a)` which is the next data available for a person.
- Because I change original input file (adding a header), I also remove this line at the end of the script. (see NOTE)
- Finally the temporary database is removed.

NOTE: I should not change the original input, but use another tempfile for that...

NOTE2:  Because CSV is a weird format, output is not what you might expect for the  `Photographer`. Output will be `" Photographer"`. For more reading on this see: [Spaces between separator and value in csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46229590/724039)

Comment: CSV isn't particularly weird IMO. Per [RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) it's OK in CSV to have spaces at the start or end of a field as long as there aren't then double quotes inside the field with the spaces outside of the quotes. So `,<blank>Photographer` as the OP has is fine and so is `,"<blank>Photographer"` but not `,<blank>"Photographer"`.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a way to do it without needing to call `mktime()` and `strftime()` nonstop at the expense of lots of regex (it should be able to handle all leap year calculations) ::

```
echo ' 
20230907,Allan,29,Marketing
20230912,Allan,29,VirtualAssistant
20230913,Allan,29,Programmer
20230920,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240317,Daniel,28, Photographer' |
```

---

```
mawk '
function ______(__, ___, ____, _____, _) {
      __ = (_ = "")__
    ____ = (_)____

    while((__ = sprintf("%d",__ += __~/([01][1-9]|10|2[0-7])$/ ?    1 \
                                 : __~                 /1231$/ ? 8870 \
       : __~/(11|[469])30$/ ? 71 : __~           /[013578]31$/ ?   70 \
       : __~/22[89]$/        &&    __~((_ = \ 
         __~"(([2468][048]|[13579][26]|(^|[0+-])[48])(00)?|"\
            "0000|^[+-]?0*)....$") ? "9$" : "8$") ? 73-_ : 1)) < ____)
        print __,
             ___, _____ 

 } BEGIN { FS =   (_ = "[ \t]*") (____ = OFS = ",")_ } {
 
     if (___[_ = $2____$3] && __[_] + 1 < +$1)
         ______(__[_], _, $1, ___[_])

     print __[_] = $1, _, ___[_] = $4 }'
```

---

```
20230907,Allan,29,Marketing
20230908,Allan,29,Marketing
20230909,Allan,29,Marketing
20230910,Allan,29,Marketing
20230911,Allan,29,Marketing
20230912,Allan,29,VirtualAssistant
20230913,Allan,29,Programmer
20230920,Daniel,28,Engineer
20230921,Daniel,28,Engineer
20230922,Daniel,28,Engineer
20230923,Daniel,28,Engineer
20230924,Daniel,28,Engineer
20230925,Daniel,28,Engineer
20230926,Daniel,28,Engineer
20230927,Daniel,28,Engineer
20230928,Daniel,28,Engineer
20230929,Daniel,28,Engineer
20230930,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231001,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231002,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231003,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231004,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231005,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231006,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231007,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231008,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231009,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231010,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231011,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231012,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231013,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231014,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231015,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231016,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231017,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231018,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231019,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231020,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231021,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231022,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231023,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231024,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231025,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231026,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231027,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231028,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231029,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231030,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231031,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231101,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231102,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231103,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231104,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231105,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231106,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231107,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231108,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231109,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231110,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231111,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231112,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231113,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231114,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231115,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231116,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231117,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231118,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231119,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231120,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231121,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231122,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231123,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231124,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231125,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231126,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231127,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231128,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231129,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231130,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231201,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231202,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231203,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231204,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231205,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231206,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231207,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231208,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231209,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231210,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231211,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231212,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231213,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231214,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231215,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231216,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231217,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231218,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231219,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231220,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231221,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231222,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231223,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231224,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231225,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231226,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231227,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231228,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231229,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231230,Daniel,28,Engineer
20231231,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240101,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240102,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240103,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240104,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240105,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240106,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240107,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240108,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240109,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240110,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240111,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240112,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240113,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240114,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240115,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240116,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240117,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240118,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240119,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240120,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240121,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240122,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240123,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240124,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240125,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240126,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240127,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240128,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240129,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240130,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240131,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240201,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240202,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240203,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240204,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240205,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240206,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240207,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240208,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240209,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240210,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240211,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240212,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240213,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240214,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240215,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240216,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240217,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240218,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240219,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240220,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240221,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240222,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240223,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240224,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240225,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240226,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240227,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240228,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240229,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240301,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240302,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240303,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240304,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240305,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240306,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240307,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240308,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240309,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240310,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240311,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240312,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240313,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240314,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240315,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240316,Daniel,28,Engineer
20240317,Daniel,28,Photographer
```